# How do check if user-input path is correct?

Tags: java, validation, user-input

I need to be prove about user-input path.
Coz when user give not folder path but file path. Program "fall down".
I understand that this is a bug but how to be ensure about user path correct.

**Code:**

```
 class PathAndWord {
    final String path;
    final String whatFind;

    PathAndWord(String path, String whatFind) {
        this.path = path;
        this.whatFind = whatFind;
    }

    boolean isProperlyInitialized() {
        return path != null && whatFind != null;
    }
}

public void askUserPathAndWord() {
    try {
        tryToAskUserPathAndWord();
    } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void tryToAskUserPathAndWord() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    PathAndWord pathAndWord = readPathAndWord();

    if (pathAndWord.isProperlyInitialized()) {
        performScan(pathAndWord, "GameOver.tmp");
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
    }
}

private PathAndWord readPathAndWord() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word (which you want to find):");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String path = readPath(bufferedReader);
    String whatFind = readWord(bufferedReader);
    return new PathAndWord(path, whatFind);
}

private String readPath(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
    return bufferedReader.readLine();
}

private String readWord(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
    return bufferedReader.readLine();
}

private void performScan(PathAndWord pathAndWord, String endOfWorkFileName) throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();

    File endOfWorkFile = new File(endOfWorkFileName);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

    FolderScan folderScan = new FolderScan(pathAndWord.path, queue, latch,
            endOfWorkFile);
    FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(pathAndWord.whatFind, queue, latch,
            endOfWorkFile);

    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executor.execute(folderScan);
    executor.execute(fileScan);

    latch.await();
}
```

**Qustions:**

- How do check if user input `path` is correct?
- If path isn't correct
  to show message that `path is wrong! Try again`.
- Able to check word - `whatFind` whether it's correct, too.
- Does need before point do?

Comment: You can create a `new File("givenPath")`. Catch the Exception so you know that the path is incorrect. If valid check if it's a dir or not.

Comment: Isn't `new File(path).exists()` and/or `newFile(path).isDirectory()` enough?

Comment: @araknoid Can you display this variant better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String readPath(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {
    boolean ok = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
        File f = new File(bufferedReader.readLine());
        if(f.exists() && f.isDirectory())
            ok = true;
        else
            System.err.println("Doesn't exist or is not a folder.");
    } while(!ok);
    return f.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

EDIT: This method does a task "read a path from user, which exists and is a directory". If the user types invalid path (non-existent or a file) the method recognizes this, warns the user and asks them again... and again and again - until they answer correctly.

It's a good custom to check data locally, if you can. When calling the method later you can be sure it returns, what you expect.

Comment: While this code may address the question asked, it is better if you add some level of description to go along with your code explaining how it addresses the question (or in this case questions).

Comment: @nazar_art I'm referring to Petr's code posted as an answer. Code only answers are generally more helpful if the author adds a one-liner to say how it addresses the problem, or to say what it does etc.